# jQuery.css() not applying to element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Recently I have been trying to delve into advanced (well for me) programming concepts like abstraction and functional programming etc. This has led me to experimenting w/ anon functions.

I have a situation where dynamically generated values are not being applied to a targeted element via an anonymous function using `.css({})`. I think it has something to do with false translations w/ object literals from my research.

Neither Chrome nor FF consoles are throwing any errors so here I am to ask the experts.

I made a fiddle, but it was not working very well. I am just going to link the resources involved on the dev site.

This is my dev site that I use to play/experiment and try out new things.

[http://dev/kenstowell.net](http://dev.kenstowell.net)

The js file: http://dev.kenstowell.net/scripts/scripts.js

Everything can be found through the debugger console, of course.

Ok, so here is what the intended behavior is:

1. On the `(window).load`, `initDOM()` is called.

   `$(window).load(function(){
      //Style Initial Dom Elements
      initDOM();
    });`
2. Inside of `initDom()`, I attempt to set the top margin in relation to the parent container by calling `setElemMargin()` and supplying it with the appropriate params.

   `setElemMarg("#main-content-one", "#intro-text", "#intro-text", "margin-top");`
3. `setElemMarg()` gets the height of the supplied args and uses them to calculate the margin to be set in the `.css()` map.

   `var setElemMarg = function(elem1, elem2, elemTrgt, propName){

     var margH = (getH(elem1) - getH(elem2)) / 2;

     $(elemTrgt).css({propName : margH});

     console.log(elem1, elem2, elemTrgt, propName, margH); 
   }`

   `var getH = function(elem){
     return $(elem).height();
     console.log($(elem).height());
   }`
4. apply the calculated margin to `margin-top`. (from above method)

   `$(elemTrgt).css({propName : margH});`

Thanks to anyone who looks at this. Please feel free to give me some constructive critique. Maybe some that you wish you had when you were a budding developer. :)

Ken

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem resides in your `setElemMarg()` function:

```
var setElemMarg = function(elem1, elem2, elemTrgt, propName) {
    var margH = (getH(elem1) - getH(elem2)) / 2;

    $(elemTrgt).css({propName : margH});  // <-- Here.

    console.log(elem1, elem2, elemTrgt, propName, margH);
}
```

The literal object syntax you're using in your call to `css()` results in jQuery trying to update a `propName` style property instead of the property whose name is stored in `propName`.

You can use bracket notation to work around this issue:

```
var styleProps = {};
styleProps[propName] = margH;
$(elemTrgt).css(styleProps);
```

Or simply call the two arguments form of [css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/#css2):

```
$(elemTrgt).css(propName, margH);
```

Comment: THANK YOU! I didn't make the connection from reading the docs the the two argument form could take var names...sigh. I kept trying to do some weird concatenation b/c I thought they needed to be strings.

Answer (score 3):

Why not try to use `$(element).attr('style','css_values');`?

Comment: Because all other inline-styles (if any) will be overwritten.

Comment: Man! I totally forgot, I have been having trouble concatenating values that include a comma like in .attr(), how do you recommend writing this with a var?

Comment: var margH = (getH(elem1) - getH(elem2)) / 2;
//
$(elemTrgt).attr('style','margin-top:' + margH + ';');   // <-- Here. *sorry, problem with code line in this textbox :p

Answer (score 0):

Since setElemMarg is called within initDOM in the window.load event, then jquery/dom is not guaranteed to be ready.  You need to call this function in the document load event

Comment: unfortunately document load is horrible for calculating widths/heights as is it called before things like images are created. [read here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7865143/jquery-height-function-returning-inaccurate-value)

Comment: you're absolutely right...I had meant to use the `$(document).ready(function() { ... });`